# Ansible Dictionary/Hash Key as Special Variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, ansible, ansible-facts

I'm trying to set an Ansible fact as a dict/hash but would like to use a special variable as the key.  In my case I want to use the special variable `inventory_hostname`. However, when I attempt this the value is returned as a string instead of the actual name of the hostname machine. How can I set the key to the special variable `inventory_hosthame` instead?

I've tried the below with no avail.

set_fact:

```
  set_fact:
    result_dict:
      "{{inventory_hostname}}": 'Linux'

  set_fact:
    result_dict:
      inventory_hostname: 'Linux'
```

Instead of the actual inventory_hostname I am being returned just the string value.

**Current Output:**

```
    ok: [host-a] => {
    "result_dict": {
        "{{inventory_hostname}}": "Linux"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your task like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        result_dict: "{{ {inventory_hostname: 'Linux'} }}"

    - debug:
        var: result_dict
```

That seems to work for me.